# Desktop looks different when running RPi on laptop over SSH?

Tags: ssh, headless

So I got my RPi 3 today and I spent a good 5 hours trying to run it headlessly because I usually use my laptop, plus I only have a DVI monitor and have to use an HDMI to DVI adapter (getting no sound either). When I connect it the orthodox way (HDMI cable to monitor, keyboard and mouse plugged in) I see the normal Raspbian DE, and it's functioning perfectly.

Then I followed a few tutorials on how to use it headlessly, and what I basically did was add `ip=169.254.0.2` in the `cmdline.txt` file on the SD card. Then I ran `ssh -Y pi@169.254.0.2`, entered the name and password, and I got to the raspberry terminal (such a success after hours of sweat and tears). However, when I run `lxsession` the screen starts flashing and in a little bit I get some taskbar on the bottom of the screen, which is nothing like the Raspbian environment (e.g. it has the Debian logo instead of the red raspberry).

My question is, is it possible to connect to the RPi over SSH using my laptop, while also getting the exact same experience as going the whole nine yards and using an external monitor and peripherals? I want to be able to develop and text on my laptop anywhere, obviously impossible the other way...

Comment: this is what VNC is for. Remote X through ssh only displays individual remote programs and their windows on your local machine using your local window manager's frames.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot run visual environment within an SSH session.

To have (almost) "*the exact same experience as going the whole nine yards and using an external monitor and peripherals*" you should set up [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).

RealVNC server comes pre-installed on Raspbian, but you need to enable it. Refer to the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) for detailed instructions.

You might however need to install VNC client like [VNCviewer](https://wiki.debian.org/VNCviewer) on your Debian machine.

Comment: `RealVNC` displays the **current** desktop, which a headless system usually won't have. The available instructions for starting it at boot are sketchy, and probably too complex for a beginner to follow.

Comment: @Milliways So OP goes "the whole nine yards" to a headless system? And when OP writes he connects "HDMI cable to monitor, keyboard and mouse plugged in" he is lying? And when he requests "the exact same experience" he actually means something different? What is your comment about?

Comment: Have you actually tried running RealVNC on a headless system? It works if you have a physical screen, but if it is really headless you can either `ssh` and manually start `vncserver` **each** time, or build a `systemd` service to start.

Comment: OP is **not** running headless! Have you actually read the question you posted an answer to? I have no clue why you are commenting under my answer. Explain your intentions, please, instead of asking about my experience.

Comment: If you are unhappy with the raspberrypi.org page I linked to, you can submit a PR on GitHub. I did not take part in its creation, so don't comment to me it's sketchy and too complex in your personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with this question.

1. `169.254.0.2` is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) and not routable. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
2. `ssh` is a protocol which is normally used to access the console and used to enter commands on a terminal.
3. If you want to see the GUI you need to use a suitable protocol. `VNC` is probably the most common. There are 2 popular flavours `RealVNC` is included in latest Raspbian. `TightVNC` is another. I will leave you to research this if you want to go this way.

Comment: OK, I downloaded VNC Viewer and it worked. However, I set a static IP to eth0 in etc/network/interfaces (it was set to "manual" previously), but now when I run ifconfig the IP address is set to 169.254.84.204...

Comment: @BobbyBrown rather than repeating the info in [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) I suggest you read this. These addresses are used **BEFORE** a normal address is assigned. You would be better connecting the Pi to your router (using Ethernet or WiFi), but is you **MUST** use static pick something in the range your network is using, often `192.168.1.nnn`